# combining duplicates (perhaps via CONCAT) in a mySQL LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, mysql, left-join, mysql-8.0

I have a list of datapoints associated with a meter. The datapoints are contiguous but over time the meter name changes, and occasionally overlaps.

meter table:

| MeterID | DataID | MeterName | ValidFrom | ValidTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Meter A | 2010-09-21 | 2015-09-17 |
| 2 | 1 | Meter B | 2015-09-15 | 2020-02-04 |
| 3 | 1 | Meter C | 2016-05-02 | 2020-09-01 |

data table:

| DataID | Value | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.9 | 2010-09-21 00:00:00 |
| 1 | ... | ... |
| 1 | 3.4 | 2020-09-01 00:00:00 |

What I'm looking for:

| Timestamp | DataID | MeterName | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| … | 1 | Meter A | … |
| 2015-09-14 23:00:00 | 1 | Meter A | 7.9 |
| 2015-09-15 00:00:00 | 1 | Meter A,Meter B | 3.0 |
| … | 1 | Meter A,Meter B | 6.3 |
| 2015-09-16 23:00:00 | 1 | Meter A,Meter B | 0.4 |
| 2015-09-17 00:00:00 | 1 | Meter B | 7.5 |
| … | 1 | Meter B | … |
| 2016-05-01 23:00:00 | 1 | Meter B | 0.6 |
| 2016-05-02 00:00:00 | 1 | Meter B,Meter C | 2.0 |
| … | 1 | Meter B,Meter C | … |
| 2020-02-03 23:00:00 | 1 | Meter B,Meter C | 3.6 |
| 2020-02-04 00:00:00 | 1 | Meter C | 9.7 |
| … | 1 | Meter C | … |

My query below results in duplicate rows where the meter timestamps overlap. Some of these overlaps can last years. There will likely never be more than 2, maybe 3 overlaps at any given point.

With over 1000 meters active at a time and 20 years worth of hourly data, the meter table is 2200 rows and the data table is almost 190M rows. My query below is very fast based on how the indexes are set up.

What is a subquery that transposes the meter names by timestamp value, similar to a PIVOT function in MySQL (v8.0.33)?

```
SELECT
    d.Timestamp,
    d.DataID,
    m.MeterName,
    d.Value
FROM
    data d
LEFT JOIN
    meter m
ON
    m.DataID = d.DataID
    AND d.Timestamp >= m.ValidFrom
    AND d.Timestamp <= m.ValidTo
WHERE
    d.DataID=1
```

Comment: Would simply adding `GROUP BY d.timestamp` to the end of the query, and changing `m.MeterNAme` to `GROUP_CONCAT(m.MeterName) AS MeterName` in the select part do what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, evidently it does. I guess I've never come across the GROUP_CONCAT function before, but that solves it

Comment: Hi. There is no question in this post. PS There is an editor bug where if you don't put a blank line in front of a table it formats even though it won't render when published. "works fine but" is a contradiction. "likely never" means "sometimes". Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Thinking is not asking a question. "not sure" is a misleading euphemism for "don't know", or for "wondering", etc.

Comment: A [mre] includes:  cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with `GROUP_CONCAT()` function:

```
SELECT
    d.Timestamp,
    d.DataID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(m.MeterName ORDER BY m.ValidFrom ASC SEPARATOR ',') AS MeterNames,
    d.Value
FROM
    data d
LEFT JOIN
    meter m
ON
    m.DataID = d.DataID
    AND d.Timestamp >= m.ValidFrom
    AND d.Timestamp <= m.ValidTo
WHERE
    d.DataID=1
GROUP BY
    d.Timestamp, d.DataID, d.Value
```

Let me know what you get..

You can read more about `GROUP_CONCAT()` function here:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-group_concat-function/

Comment: wow, thanks for the super quick response - dunno how I've never come across GROUP_CONCAT() before, but that worked like a charm. As did @GMB's response. I'll have to benchmark them and see which performs better, but both are valid solutions so I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good spot to use a lateral join (this requires MySQL 8.0.14 at least):

```
SELECT d.Timestamp, d.DataID, m.MeterNames, d.Value
FROM data d
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(m.MeterName ORDER BY m.ValidFrom) meterNames
    FROM meter m
    WHERE m.DataID = d.DataID
      AND d.Timestamp >= m.ValidFrom
      AND d.Timestamp <= m.ValidTo
) m
WHERE d.DataID = 1
```

In earlier versions, we can get the same behavior with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT d.Timestamp, d.DataID, 
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(m.MeterName ORDER BY m.ValidFrom)
        FROM meter m
        WHERE m.DataID = d.DataID
          AND d.Timestamp >= m.ValidFrom
          AND d.Timestamp <= m.ValidTom
    ) MeterNames, 
    d.Value
FROM data d
WHERE d.DataID = 1
```

I would expect this technique to be more efficient than `left join` + `group by`, since it avoids outer aggregation - especially if you have an index on `meter (DataID, ValidFrom,ValidTom)`.

Comment: wow, thanks for the super quick response - This solution also worked (I first tried @Manoj's response, which also worked). As noted in my comment to him, I'll be interested to see which of the two works fastest (I used CROSS JOIN LATERAL in my test, as I'm on 8.0.33)